# Xcode app version not compatible with Mac OS X version

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsfilemanager, nsfilehandle, osx-leopard

am using Os X 10.6.4 and X code Version 3.2.3 for developing some simple app files and using PackageMaker to distribute these app files. But when trying to run the package on some other mac I am getting error that the package is not compatible with the Os X its running and file would not be installed. Is this a problem with X code or package maker. sorry for reposting it but although I tried changing base SDK to 10.5, it was getting compiled and ran well on mac I am using for development (Mac OS X 10.6.4) but when installed on mac running OS X 10.5 the .app files were grayed out and message poped up saying 'you cannot use this version of application with this version of Mac'. Any idea why is this happening? Also as mentioned earlier I am using IBOutlet for accepting user date from form and then writing that into a text file. Any idea or solution about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have anything set in your Info.plist for the LSMinimumSystemVersion key? This is one place the system looks.

Comment: i have modified my info.plist but havent touch LSMinimumSystemVersion key. Although I am developing on OS X 10.6 and was using base SDK 10.6 previously, so does this mean that I will have to go and change the LSMinimumSystemVersion key attribute. sorry if my Q doesn't make any sense I am completely new to mac os X and Xcode...

Comment: Aniket: That doesn't answer the question; he asked if you have it set in Info.plist. If it was 10.6 and you haven't changed it, then it's still 10.6, which would explain the problem, and the solution would be to change it (to 10.5).

Comment: okay sorry for any confusion, now I have set LSMinimumSystemVersion key attribute to '10.5.1' and he base sdk is also set to 10.5 and GCC 4.0 for all configurations. Now the project is compiling and running successfully on my mac. I can also see the value of LSMinimumSystemVersion set to 10.5.1 in release app content. But I dont have mac with OS X 10.5 right now I will get the actual test results tomorrow. But ideally if the project is compiling and running with all above configurations then it should run on Mac Os X 10.5 right? or there is still possibility that it might not run?

Comment: Unless 10.5.1 is absolutely required, you should go with the base 10.5.0, but yes, it *should* work. Let us know (and remember to accept answers if they work for you). :-)

Comment: Yes, sure :) About the 10.5.0, if I specify 10.5.1 does this means that it will not work on 10.5.0 that is the original DVD release version ?

Comment: If you specify 10.5.1, it will only run on 10.5.1 or above.

Comment: sorry for late reply but I was not having Mac running OSX 10.5 handy to test the app but now I have one. As suggested changing SDK and LSMinimumSystemVersion key trick worked for me except the file handling part, where i am accepting information from user and writing it in a file. I am using createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attr' and createfileatpath from NSFilemanager. I read that createDirectoryAtPath:attributes is deprecated in OSX10.5. What exactly does this mean? 'createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:'  will work in OSX10.5 or no?

Answer (score 0):

When I was brand new I had trouble figuring this out...
Make sure that your Base SDK and deployment target are 10.5 and that you have the right compiler on(GCG4.0/4.2), also make sure that when you change these settings you change it for both Release and Debug, I once made this mistake of changing it only on debug, and when I built for release it only worked on 10.6 because I didn't change those settings.